# Rails: how to initialize and set boolean instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It must be simple, but I can't get it to work:
- I want to initialize an instance variable (boolean) in my model
- then I want to set this variable in a view with (simple)form (checkbox).
howto?
thnx!

Comment: I'm looking for the answer @Max gave. Please have a look at my comment to his suggestion? thnx, Berry

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that you want a virtual that is not backed by a database column.

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :happy

  def intialize
    @happy = false
    super # very important!
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= simple_form_for(@thing) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :happy, as: :checkbox %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thnx for your advise & sorry for my late answer (been away for 2 days). This is indeed what I'm looking for, However, when I follow your procedure, it seems that `@happy` does not change by setting the checkbox to true. Neither is the checkbox updated by submitting. If I cal `#{@happy}` nothing (empty, blank) is returned. I was expecting `true` or `false`. So I'm close to the solution, almost there. Any other suggestions for me? thnx in advance ... Berry

Comment: I've added `:happy` to permitted params, but that didn't solve it.